# Left join in (flask)sqlalchemy with getting unmatched values and filter on the right table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get a list of all assignments, with the progress of the user (the UserAssignments table) also in the result set. That means there should be a join between the assignments and userassignments table (where the assignmentid is equal), but also a filter to check if the progress is from the current user. The diagram of the database and the actual models are listed below.

```
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    roleid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.roleid'), nullable=False)
    groups = db.relationship('Group', secondary=users_groups, lazy='dynamic')
    assignments = db.relationship('Assignment', secondary=users_assignments, lazy='dynamic')

class Assignment(db.Model):
    assignmentid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    assignmentname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    assignmentranking = db.Column(db.Integer)
    assignmentquestion = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Assignment {}>'.format(self.assignmentid)

class UserAssignments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_assignments'
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    assignmentid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('assignment.assignmentid'), primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)
    progress = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<UserAssignments {}>'.format(self.userid, self.assignmentid)
```

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LF4Q.png)

I tried the following query, but that resulted only the assignments with a matched userassignment (progress). (the userid is given into the function)

```
results = db.session.query(Assignment, UserAssignments).join(UserAssignments, (UserAssignments.assignmentid == Assignment.assignmentid)&(UserAssignments.userid==userid), isouter=True).filter(UserAssignments.userid==userid).all()
```

I also tried the query without the filter, but that resulted in all userassignments (also from other users).

```
results = db.session.query(Assignment, UserAssignments).join(UserAssignments, (UserAssignments.assignmentid == Assignment.assignmentid)&(UserAssignments.userid==userid), isouter=True).all()
```

As said earlier, I want to achieve a result with all assignments listed, with the userassignment included when there is one for the current user.

Comment: For clarity: I want to display an overview page for assignments, where all assignments are listed, with their status (if they have any progress).

Answer (score 0):

try next query

```
results = db.session.query(
   Assignment, 
   UserAssignments,
).join(
   UserAssignments, 
   UserAssignments.assignmentid == Assignment.assignmentid, 
   isouter=True,
).filter(
   or_(
      UserAssignments.userid == userid,
      UserAssignments.userid.is_(None),
   )
).all()
```

Comment: This also returns only the assignments with user progress, but not assignments without user progress.

Comment: changed query, try now

Comment: The 'is None' returns an empty result, probably because there is no UserAssignment when there is no progress.

Comment: So did you try ? Are there any problems ?